# Use of After Effects files in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, lottie, flare

I know how to export **Rive** (Flare) files to use in Flutter apps but how can I **import** Adobe **After Effects** files to Rive?

I know it is possible to do with **Lottie** but I am unable to figure out how to exactly do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily import the bodymovin json file. Check the attached image.

[rive.com online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by74e.png)

Comment: Got it. So I need to install **bodymovin** plugin in After Effects and export my animation as json which I can import in Rive. Thanks.

Comment: You can also test existing animations by downloading the JSON from https://lottiefiles.com/ and import them into Rive. I am so glad it helped. Welcome <3

Answer (score 0):

Use BodyMovin plugin in Adobe After effects and export to .flr2d directly(which can be opened in rive.app)

https://twitter.com/rive_app/status/1216032029613154306?lang=en