# Animate After Effects animations natively in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, after-effects

We have a team that will create AE animations (including parallax, sound effects etc.) and I need to play those animations on Android as exactly they are, triggering them by swipe. For Android and AE first thing comes into mind is Lottie, that I've tried for small stuff. But what we need is more advanced and complex.

Only thing that I need to do is taking the AE animation and play them on Android.

Maybe it's possible with Unity, but as I've never worked with Unity, it's out of my knowledge how to do it.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: This feels like recommendation so may be off-topic. Regardless consider Flutter & Rive (was Flare): [Use of After Effects files in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59404997/295004)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Will try it!

Comment: So, I managed to use my json animation exported from AE, on Rive!. Next step is working with it on Flutter ^^ @MorrisonChang

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do complex animation on android using After Effects still you can go to Unity Documentation and search Android Animation to know more. [Unity Documentation Android Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/30_search.html?q=android%20animation)